# Php formatting float number

Tags: php, mysql, types

I have data in MySQL data type decimal(13,6). I filtering this data in php with `sprintf('%.2f', $number)`

How to get real data when $number padded last positive number? Also examples below.

Like, get example outputs with sprintf.

```
(mysql real value)   (filter function)

1.000000             1.00
0.100000             0.10
0.001000             0.001 // only this value geting 0.00 in sprintf('%.2f', $number). We need get 0.001
0.000000             0.00
```

Comment: What do you mean by "real data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this might work:

```
$number = sprintf('%f',floatval("1.0E-5"));
$number = $number < 0.01 && $number !== 0 ? (string) $number : sprintf('%.2f', $number);
```

Comment: Good. But when "0.000000" value returns  "0".  I can get formatted like "0.00" ?

Comment: Yes. This is price format. We showing positive format when 0.001 last one padded.

Comment: what about 0.00011? what you would expect?

Comment: @Ali check previous comment please

Comment: so it works or there is other cases to take care of? @Ali

Comment: 1.0E-5 getting when value 0.00001. Can get without E-5 ?

Comment: Yes but string value showing wrong. I know same as. But i dont show to users to 1.0E-5.